# Batch Programming scope confusion while running

Tags: batch-file

I have a list of property files which have key value pair as shown below in config folder.

```
PERIOD=1
RUN_MONTH=1605
PD_THRU_MONTH=1604
INCURD_BEGIN_DT=2015-03-01
```

Im trying to run a script to execute a sql statement using these as parameter. But when i run this code

```
@echo off
for /r %%i in (config\*) do (
setlocal
FOR /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%K IN (config\%%~ni.prm) DO ( 
    IF "%%K"=="PERIOD"                  (
        Set FILE_PERIOD=%%L 
        echo %FILE_PERIOD%
        )
    )
endlocal
```

It returns the `PERIOD` of the last file, in my case `9`. But when I replace the block inside `IF` with `echo %%L` it prints out the correct numbers.

Im new to batch programming and am finding this really confusing. I've been looking into the FOR loop syntax and whatnot, but I still can't find what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Also Im using windows 10 if that makes a difference.

Comment: You need [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) since you are modifying *and* reading the same variable (`FILE_PERIOD`) within a parenthesised block of code...

Comment: thanks for the link. went through it and solved the problem.